# Everyone lives in advanced underwater ships (not SeaQuest)

Tags: story-identification, tv

I was hospitalized recently and a show would come on very late at night about a world where everyone lived in underwater ships, I guess land was no longer livable or available. I've searched and searched and all that comes up is *SeaQuest*. This was much better quality and was filmed much more realistic so I'm guessing it was produced more recently than *SeaQuest*. There were huge ships with lots of people in each one. It was like they were in a spaceship but underwater.

It was a show, on every night. I'm not sure of the channel but it was definitely an ongoing plot. The people were definitely from Earth, and Earth had flooded completely, hence why they were living in this underwater world on these huge ships that traveled all around the globe. The ships resembled spaceships even though they were high tech submarines.

It was in color, a seemingly recent show (no older than the 90s) and was NOT *Stargate Atlantis* or *The Girl from Tomorrow*. One of the plots there was a big something in the way underwater and the ship had underestimated where it was in it's path and it almost hit the obstacle.

Comment: Color or black and white? Did the episode have a name? What network? How long was the episode?

Comment: How many episodes did you see?  Are you sure they were on Earth?

Comment: Stargate Atlantis?

Comment: Was it a movie, a miniseries or an ongoing series? Do you remember any plot details?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider - is there a reason you've bountied this?

Comment: I'd just like to know the answer, it sounds interesting.

Comment: There's a season (last season I think) of Sea Quest called Sea Quest 2032 where they jump into the future, maybe it is that?

Comment: Maybe there might be something in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Underwater_civilizations_in_fiction? Plus I have a *vague* memory of maybe some underwater city scenes in "The Girl from Tomorrow"?

Comment: It was a show, on every night, I'm not sure if the channel but it was definitely an ongoing plot. The people were definitely from earth and earth had flooded completely, hence why they were living in this underwater world on these huge ships that traveled all around the globe. The ships resembled spaceships even though they were high tech submarines. I still haven't figured it out but I know it was a show for sure.

Comment: Also it was in color, a seemingly recent show (no older than the 90s) and was NOT Stargate Atlantis or the Girl from Tomorrow. One of the plots there was a big something in the way underwater and the ship had underestimated where it was in it's path and it almost hit the obstacle. Sorry I don't have better descriptions, I was in the hospital so long and it came on late late every night so I would catch it because insomnia but the in depth details are hard to remember but I really want to watch it now because it was really good(at least I thought it was while hospitalized lol)

Comment: @candi please edit these details in your question instead of writing them in comments.

Comment: If it was on "every night" it was in reruns.  But it seems the OP hasn't been back in more than a year...

Comment: My money is still on SeaQuest 2032

Comment: To spare someone else the effort ... just for fun I asked two AI bots to identify it based on the description. Both identified it as "The 100" at first, after clarifying that it has to be from before 2019 ChatGPT suggested "The Last Ship" while the Azure OpenAI based bot suggested "The Expanse". Another waste of time.